# Silver matrix properties of order n

Tags: matrices, recreational-mathematics

A square matrix of order n is a silver matrix if any i-th row and the i-th column contain all the
elements from 1 to 2 − 1. Show that there is no silver matrix of order 1997.
I can see by trial that it works for even n cases upto 4 but can't prove it. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @José Carlos Santos , thanks for it but I am unable to progress on it. I have been thinking of creating a set containing the off diagonal elements of i th row and i th column but after that I am completely blank. If any insight is possible.  Also i have found a pattern that every diagonal elements are same but don't want to use it as i cannot generalise it.

Comment: Source of the question is probably IMO.

Comment: Indeed. problem 4 of https://sms.math.nus.edu.sg/SIMO/IMO_Problems/97.pdf

Comment: Can you please elaborate how in this pdf they are getting to conclusion n is even. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an elaboration of the parity argument.

There are $2n-1$ different numbers in the array, and only $n$ entries on the diagonal, so if $n>1$ there must be some number $x$ that doesn't occur on the diagonal.  (Note that if $n=1$ the $1\times1$ matrix whose only entry is $1$ is a silver matrix.)

For $i=1,2,\dots,n$, $x$ occurs once in the $i$th row and $i$th column.  That is, there is a $1\leq j\leq n$ with $j\neq i$ such that exactly one of $a_{ij}=x$ and $a_{ji}=x$ is true.  Let us assign $j$ to $i$.  The same procedure assigns $i$ to $j$, for there cannot be a $k\neq i$ such that $a_{jk}=x$ or $a_{kj}=x$.

This procedure groups the numbers $1,2,\dots,n$ into pairs, so $n$ is even.

Comment: Thanks . Can you please explain Let us assign j to i., this part and then assignment of i to j. What does this assignment means.

Comment: Ok , i understood the solution. Thanks a lot @saulspatz.

Comment: @User1 My pleasure.  If an answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark, so it leaves the unsolved queue.